# How to show flash content on android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I've a HTML file which has flash content.Here the flash content is an custom player.I just want to show it on android webview(to play tht video).I've installed Adobe flash player on my device too.I used below code.when i run it show white screen.nothing play backing.Did i made any mistake on this?

My code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. Along with flash player, try installing Adobe air too. sometimes only flash player is not enough to run some flash components. Plus just for the sake of argument check your index.html on your machines browser that it is working correctly. If yes then installing air may fix your problem else you need to fix the html first.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29) of WebSetting, the method `setPluginsEnabled` is deprecated. Try using [setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29) instead. Something like:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: it is already there: webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: @mudit setJavaScriptEnabled is not the same as setPluginState

Comment: my bad, i copied the wrong line: webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);